# Loading a React component into html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cdn, jsdelivr

I am trying to load a html page on my browser which should have a React component embedded. I am using a CDN to access the React component. Inside the file that the CDN url contains, a function, which returns a React component, is defined and exported. I try to access that function in the html, using the syntax:

```
<body>
    <div id="my-div"></div>
    <script type='text-babel'>
        props = {}
        const chart = window.my_function(props) # Should return a react component
        ReactDOM.render(chart, document.getElementById("my-div"))
    </script>
</body>
```

where props is a filled js object, and react, reactDOM and the file itself are loaded in the header black above.

Where could i be going wrong? the webpage loads but it is completely empty

Comment: That isn't how React components work, at all. React components *are* functions, that take props, and are called with those props *by the React runtime*. That isn't a function that returns a component, it *is* a component. You don't want to call it, you're looking for [React.createElement](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So in the return statement of the component create in the CDN, React.createElement is called with the props, which in that case should be what returns to the chart variable right? Have I not called the component correctly?

Comment: You have not. It should be something like `ReactDOM.render(() => React.createElement(window.my_function, props), document.getElementById('my-div'))`. I'm pretty sure you need to wrap the createElement call in an anonymous function, it's been a minute since I wrote React without using JSX